# What's the best practice of configuring logging in Python?

Tags: python, logging, pep8

It seems that `logging` is not that easy to use in Python. For example, I need to use `logging` for logs, and I also need to import other stuff from some other packages.

If I write my code like below:

```
import logging
import foo
from bar import baz

logging.basicConfig(...)
```

the logs will not output as I configured in `basicConfig()`, they will be output in the default format. So the `basicConfig()` doesn't work in this case.

If I write my code like below:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(...)

import foo
from bar import baz
```

The logs will be output as I configured in `basicConfig()`, but the code style does not obey PEP8, because `logging.basicConfig()` appears among the import statements.

Is there any solution for it so that I can have it both ways?

Comment: `basicConfig()` does not change the logging configuration if there is already one. So, I guess one of your imports does some logging config already.

Comment: The above comment is probably the answer you are looking for, but without details about how the code you `import` manipulated its logging, this is not a [mre]